# Insert Column Label into pivot table by using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, pivot, apache-poi

I've created a pivot table using Apache POI 3.11. like this:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path+fname));

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new  XSSFWorkbook(file);

XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
//area of pivot data
AreaReference a=new AreaReference("A1:J4");

CellReference b=new CellReference("N5");    
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(a,b);

//insert row
pivotTable.addRowLabel(3);
pivotTable.addRowLabel(6);

//insert column
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 5);

//export
FileOutputStream output_file = 
   new FileOutputStream(new File(path+"POI_XLS_Pivot_Example.xlsx")); 
workbook.write(output_file);//write excel document to output stream
output_file.close(); //close the file
```

After I generated the report, it shows the row correctly. But it doesn't show a column label:

[image: img]

I want to display the column label in my pivot table like this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [pivot-table.com](http://www.pivot-table.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/calculateditem04.png))</sub>

Does anyone know the solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: At this moment I've exactly the same problem! Well, since it's a beta version, it's probably not possible right now... It's a pity, that there is no method `addColumnLabel(int)` which would add a column label without a data consolidation function... I searched for some sample code and found this: https://code.google.com/p/web-design-r/source/browse/trunk/zpoiex-r/src/org/zkoss/zpoiex/ss/usermodel/helpers/PivotTableHelper.java?r=15  The `createPivotTable` method looks interesting where they handle some `CTPivotField`s. Don't know, if there is a way through these fields?!

Comment: Did you get this to work? the Create addColumnLabel as shown in below answers still does not work..thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following method (a slightly modified version of XSSFPivotTable.addRowLabel) adds a "normal" pivot column label:

```
public static void addColLabel(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable, int columnIndex) {
    AreaReference pivotArea = new AreaReference(pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition()
            .getCacheSource().getWorksheetSource().getRef());
    int lastRowIndex = pivotArea.getLastCell().getRow() - pivotArea.getFirstCell().getRow();
    int lastColIndex = pivotArea.getLastCell().getCol() - pivotArea.getFirstCell().getCol();

    if (columnIndex > lastColIndex) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    CTPivotFields pivotFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields();

    CTPivotField pivotField = CTPivotField.Factory.newInstance();
    CTItems items = pivotField.addNewItems();

    pivotField.setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
    pivotField.setShowAll(false);
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastRowIndex; i++) {
        items.addNewItem().setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
    }
    items.setCount(items.sizeOfItemArray());
    pivotFields.setPivotFieldArray(columnIndex, pivotField);

    CTColFields rowFields;
    if (pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields() != null) {
        rowFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields();
    } else {
        rowFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields();
    }

    rowFields.addNewField().setX(columnIndex);
    rowFields.setCount(rowFields.sizeOfFieldArray());
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since version [3.12 of POI](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.12), it's working like a charm (also with own column labels):

```
//insert column
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 2, "Central");
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 3, "East");
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 4, "West");
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 5, "Grand Total");
```

Comment: What POI calls a "Column Label" is shown as a "Value" in Excel.  This method should be called addValue

Comment: This solution has not reason, because second parameter of `pivotTable.addColumnLabe` is `columnIndex` of **source**.